# react-router-dom 6 upgrade help: All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

Our application recently updated to the beta versions of react-router-dom, and things were fine. Then when I try to update to 6.0.2, I get lots of invariant errors about `All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`. This is because we have our routes defined as follows:

Feature.jsx:

```
export const FeatureRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Feature1 />} />
    <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

routes.jsx:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: "feature",
    component: FeatureRoutes,
  },
  /* lots of other routes, defined the same way: <Route> wrapped in a component */
];
```

App.jsx:

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map((route) => (
    <Route key={route.path} path={`${pathPrefix}/${route.path}/*`}>
      <route.component />
    </Route>
  ))}
</Routes>
```

This now results in the error above, because the inner routes (for example `FeatureRoutes`) are wrapped in a functional component. I've tried returning the literal JSX but then get another error. I'm not sure how to fix this: is the only answer to completely rewrite how we define our routes? We also have some routes that are stored in the back-end and map to custom components - again I'm not sure how I can wrap these now I'm not allowed to have a component between Routes and Route.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a small refactor will get your app rendering again.

In the `routes` array rename `component` to `Component` so it can be rendered as a React component, i.e. as a properly named React component (PascalCased).

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "feature",
    Component: FeatureRoutes
  }
  /* lots of other routes, defined the same way: <Route> wrapped in a component */
];
```

When mapping the `routes` render the `Component` out on the `Route` component's `element` prop ***as JSX***.

```
<Routes>
  {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
    <Route
      key={path}
      path={`${pathPrefix}/${path}/*`}
      element={<Component />}
    />
  ))}
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-6-upgrade-help-all-component-children-of-routes-must-be-a-r]